# XMLTokenizeLanguage on camel split EIP

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a question about `XMLTokenizeLanguage` more specifically about [`XMLTokenExpressionIterator.java`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-3.18.x/core/camel-xml-jaxp/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/language/xtokenizer/XMLTokenExpressionIterator.java):

[image: screenshot]

`this.splitpath` accepts multiple tokens separated by "/".

I try to use it in this way: ==>

```
.split(body().xtokenize("/ns1:[some type]/ns1:[another type]" 'i', ns))
    .streaming()
```

where ns and ns1 are namespaces

But no result in the pipeline

Can you please share with me more content about `XMLTokenizeLanguage`.

The example in Camel website is about split of XML by 1 type [JAXB java POJO], what about 2 or more types [JAXB java POJOs]? is it even possible?

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/eips/split-eip.html

This is my XML Content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<LocationMessages xmlns="http://standards.iso.org/iso/15143/-3">
    <Links>
        <rel>self</rel>
        <href>https://[source domain name ]/public/api/aemp/v2/15143/-3/Fleet/Equipment/ID/[equipement id]/Locations/2021-01-01T00:00/2022-09-28T09:34:06.439553/1</href>
    </Links>
    <Links>
        <rel>last</rel>
        <href>https://[source domain
            name]/public/api/aemp/v2/15143/-3/Fleet/Equipment/ID/[equipement
            id]/Locations/2021-01-01T00:00/2022-09-
            28T09:34:06.439553/1</href>
    </Links>
    <Location datetime="2022-04-05T09:52:53Z">
        <Latitude>43.290143</Latitude>
        <Longitude>5.491987</Longitude>
        <Altitude>102.375</Altitude>
        <AltitudeUnits>metre</AltitudeUnits>
    </Location>
    <Location datetime="2022-05-04T13:50:57Z">
        <Latitude>43.289926</Latitude>
        <Longitude>5.492582</Longitude>
        <Altitude>77.0</Altitude>
        <AltitudeUnits>metre</AltitudeUnits>
    </Location>
</LocationMessages>
```

This is namespace declaration :

```
Namespaces ns = new Namespaces("ns1", "http://standards.iso.org/iso/15143/-3");
```

And this is the split by xtokenize language  definition :

```
.split(body().xtokenize("/ns1:Links/ns1:Location", 'i', ns)).streaming()
```

The split xtokenize work for me when I use 1 type at a time ( Links or Location), but I don't want to use (.multicast()) to duplicate pipeline.

I want tokenize by 2 types (Links and Location) and after that apply content routing EIP (choice()) to choose the route for every token type.

Links and Location are JAXB pojo types generated by xjc from xsd schemas.
Here a brief part of their structure  :

---

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Links", propOrder = {
    "rel",
    "href"
})
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", comments = "JAXB RI v3.0.2", date = "2022-08-23T15:17:27+02:00")
public class Links {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", comments = "JAXB RI v3.0.2", date = "2022-08-23T15:17:27+02:00")
    protected String rel;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", comments = "JAXB RI v3.0.2", date = "2022-08-23T15:17:27+02:00")
    protected String href;
```

---

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Location", propOrder = {
    "latitude",
    "longitude",
    "altitude",
    "altitudeUnits"
})
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", comments = "JAXB RI v3.0.2", date = "2022-08-23T15:17:27+02:00")
public class Location {

    @XmlElement(name = "Latitude", required = true)
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", comments = "JAXB RI v3.0.2", date = "2022-08-23T15:17:27+02:00")
    protected BigDecimal latitude;
    @XmlElement(name = "Longitude", required = true)
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", comments = "JAXB RI v3.0.2", date = "2022-08-23T15:17:27+02:00")
    protected BigDecimal longitude;
    @XmlElement(name = "Altitude")
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", comments = "JAXB RI v3.0.2", date = "2022-08-23T15:17:27+02:00")
    protected BigDecimal altitude;
    @XmlElement(name = "AltitudeUnits")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", comments = "JAXB RI v3.0.2", date = "2022-08-23T15:17:27+02:00")
    protected Altitudeuom altitudeUnits;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "datetime", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", comments = "JAXB RI v3.0.2", date = "2022-08-23T15:17:27+02:00")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar datetime;
```

---

Comment: Hi, It is XMLTokenizeLanguage a full language ? with logical operator ( or , and, ... etc) and with more instructions ?

Comment: Please provide your input XML content and the real expression used as parameter of the method `xtokenize`

Comment: please add a simple example to your question instead of as comment

Comment: Sorry I tried to edit it in the summary, feel free to ask more details

Comment: Hello Nicolas, Is the XML content understandable to you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `xtokenize` expression to include all its potential children which are `Links` and `Location` according to [its schema definition](https://standards.iso.org/iso/15143/-3/ed-1/en/Locations.xsd) by using the wildcard character `*`.

The right code for the `split` should then be `.split(body().xtokenize("/ns1:LocationMessages/ns1:*", 'i', ns)).streaming()`

Comment: Thank you Nicolas , I will test your suggestion.

Comment: That's work for me the split with 2 types but xtokenise in predicate of choice() not yet :   `.split(body().xtokenize("/ns1:LocationMessages/ns1:*", 'i', ns)).streaming()
                     //   .log("body telematics first split : ${body}")
                .choice().when(body().xtokenize("/ns1:Links", 'i', ns))` he doesn't match for the path requested.

Comment: This is another question, please avoid mixing questions, create a new question instead

Comment: Ok I will create new question for this feature. Thank you a lot

Comment: In case someone interested for the 2nd question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73895301/camel-xmltokenizelanguage-on-content-based-router-predicate-choice