# How to use the XML Tokenize language as a predicate in a Content based Router?

Tags: java, apache-camel

Can we use `body().xtokenize` as predicate of `choice()` in Camel pipeline for routing when XML type matches the path we want?

I tried it but doesn't filter in accordance with the predicate :

This is the code snippet :

```
 Namespaces ns = new Namespaces("ns1", "http://standards.iso.org/iso/15143/-3");
.choice().when(body().xtokenize("/ns1:Links", 'i', ns))
```

These are the type of XML content that I would like to route according to the name of the root element:

```
<Links xmlns="http://standards.iso.org/iso/15143/-3">
    <rel>last</rel>
    <href>https://[source domain name]/public/api/aemp/v2/15143/-3/Fleet/Equipment/ID/[equipment
        id]/Locations/2021-01-01T00:00/2022-09-29T12:52:12.519982300/1
    </href>
</Links>
```

Or

```
<Location datetime="2022-04-05T09:52:53Z">
    <Latitude>43.290143</Latitude>
    <Longitude>5.491987</Longitude>
    <Altitude>102.375</Altitude>
    <AltitudeUnits>metre</AltitudeUnits>
</Location>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **XML Tokenize** language is not really meant to be used as a predicate, you should rather use another language like the **XPath** language for example.

Your **Content Based Router** could test the local name of the root element to route your messages as next:

```
.choice()
    .when().xpath("/*[local-name()='Links']")
        .log("Link detected ${body}")
    .when().xpath("/*[local-name()='Location']")
        .log("Location detected ${body}")
    .otherwise()
        .log("Unknown ${body}");
```

Comment: Thank you Nicolas. For the moment I proceed by startsWith ==> like that : body().startsWith("<Links")  , I will observe the performance if it worse I will switch to XPATH

Comment: @Mohamedr if so propose your answer and if it is good enough for you, you can accept your own answer